# laravel cron tasks with liebig/cron

Tags: laravel, cron

I'm trying to set up a CRON job for my laravel 4.2 app and am strugglng to get things to work.

I've created a command which works successfully from the command line. I first tried created a CRON task with my service provider but was unable to get this to work. I tried:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/vhosts/mydomin.co.uk/subdomains/golfmanager/httpdocs/artisan reminder:week
```

This does not appear to work

I then tried:

```
/usr/bin/lynx -dump /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.co.uk/subdomains/golfmanager/httpdocs/artisan reminder:week
```

That failed to work either. My understanding is Lynx is a browser? but I assume because all the traffic is re-routed this approach won't work for a Laravel app?

So I then installed the package [liebig/cron][1]  with a view to getting that up and running. I created a cron task with an external provider 'cronservice' which appears to be triggering but I'm not getting the expected results from the task.

I have configured the package as described and have current placed the following in `bootstratp/start.php`

```
Event::listen('cron.collectJobs', function() {
Cron::add('reminder-week', '*/15 * * * *', function() {

    echo "Running Task";
    Artisan::call('reminder:week');
    return true;
});


});
```

The package logs activity to a database. I can see a log entry suggesting it's fired but can't see an entry that the job has worked. Laravel log files suggest there is an httpfoundexception

I've not created a route for CRON - the readme suggests it's using an internal one?

I'm quite confused. I'd like to stick with the package approach and the external provider but not sure if I now need to create a route and how I can test the set up is correct and the jobs will work.

I've tried running the script from the browser `http://mydomain.com/cron.php?key=xxxxx' but that also throws an httpnotfound exception

ANy help appreciated to get this to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `Event::listen` code to `app/start/glopal.php` and all working now.

Re-read the readme more carefully!

Comment: https://github.com/liebig/cron#addjob I am trying the first example. I have placed it in the global.php as the doc says. The job should run every minute as it says but nothing happens?